# Facebook Connect with Java Smack 4

Tags: java, facebook, xmpp

With this example I'm trying to get the number of Facebook friends to connect, but I get an error

```
       XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection("chat.facebook.com");
       connection.connect();
       connection.login("asdd@asd.com", "pass");
       Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
       Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
       System.out.println(entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
```

output:

23, 2014 2:23:04 PM org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.IQReplyFilter accept
WARNING: Rejected potentially spoofed reply to IQ-packet. Filter settings: packetId=JR6jj-0, to=null, local=null, server=chat.facebook.com. Received packet with from=asdd@asd.com@chat.facebook.com

I'm using version Smack4.0.3

Comment: Which Smack version do you use?